# Interpolation of data using interpolate.interp1d in python with datetime as index

Tags: python, datetime, interpolation

I have some health data of people that are not regular during the day.

In order to make use of it, I want to interpolate the data in regular periods of time during the day (each 30 minutes). Therefore, I tried to use the function `interpolate.interp1d`.

Executing:

```
f = interpolate.interp1d(data['pump_timestamp'], data['denormalized_glucose_value'])
datelist = pd.date_range(start = date(year, month, day), periods=48, freq='30min').tolist()
ynew = f(datelist)
```

Results in the following error:

> ValueError: object arrays are not supported

How should I modify my code to make it work?

Comment: You can convert the datetimes to minutes or hours with respect to some offset.

Comment: Please share your whole code so I can have a look on this. Right now, it seems too vague.